# How to create HTML Data entry form using Google spreadsheet as backend

Tags: html, r, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a google spreadsheet, where some rows append on daily basis and using the google spreadsheet, the customer feedback team follows up.

Google Spreadsheet Data.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1V-XZdCUZAQVkfCat9vXVxITjjNMxNMPDin6B5j9uMWY/edit?usp=sharing

The above mentioned Google Spreadsheet always have the below mentioned data at google sheet (Highlighted in blue):

Ref ID
Company Name
Contact No.1
Contact No.2
Project Name
Agent ID

Rest of the mentioned details would be captured from the HTML UI basis the user response and finally click on 'Submit & Next' or 'Next' the input get stored at google sheet.

The User has to first enter the 'Agent Id' on HTML UI and accordingly one by one `Ref ID` detail would be given to particular 'Agent Id` user.

As mentioned in the attached screenshot, The left side of the information would be static as per the googlespread sheet, and right hand side information would be filled by the user basis the telephonic conversation.

Below mentioned particulars will be drop down or radio options basis user input:

```
Product : Lite, Lite-I, Elite
Ref Code: LIT-1, LIT-2, LIT-3
Status  : Accept, Reject, Pending
Comment : Satisfied, Call Back, Pending
```

Below mentioned particulars will be derived:

```
Days Passed: It will be derived from the current system year - year mentioned in the `Date`
```

Below mentioned particulars will be user input as a free text.

```
Client Name
Notes
Final_Status
```

**Note:** The agents will be assigned and shown only those `Ref ID` where the `Agent ID` is not blank and `Final_Status` is either blank or other than 'Submit & Next' marked in Googlespread Sheet.

We need to add one more column in the Googlespread sheet, Which capture the Date time stamp as per the system date as soon as the `Final_Status` marked as 'Submit & Next` or 'Next'

Submit & Next button would only be enable if all the details are captured by user. 
Next Button would only be enable if `Comment` option is selected.

Also, If there is no new rows available in the googlesheet for the data entry using UI, the UI will throw the message to User that there is 'No New task available' on a blank screen by clicking on 'Submit & Next' or 'Next' button.

Expected UI:

[image]

Comment: Where is your attempt at doing this, at solving your **very broad** question? No one is going to give you a turnkey solution to this in exchange for 50 rep.

Comment: @tehhowch: Hmmm...my bad.

Comment: Your question seemingly asks for an entire business solution, something that generally requires $$$$ to obtain and then also to maintain. Please review what constitutes a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @tehhowch: Hahaha...its a simply a class project.

Comment: You're wasting your reps. At least include  your attempt at solution and whether there's a specific problem in your attempt. May be then, others will be able to help. Class project or not,  the  time needed to complete the code you're requesting will take hours.

Comment: @tehhowch it's 300reps

Comment: @themaster the first bounty was 50. No one did the OP's project for them, so rather than award the bounty, they updated the bounty requirement to "canonical answer" and upped the reward to 300.

Comment: @tehhowch I see. Also wondering how it got +7 upvotes(-5). Vote manipulation may be... one can speculate..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Data Entry Dialog Created from Header Info on Spreadsheet**

Code.gs:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("My Menu")
  .addItem('Launch Dialog','launchTheFormAsDialog')
  .addToUi();
}

function buildForm() {
  var searchColumnName='RefId';
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var tA=sh.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var hA=sh.getRange(2,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  tA.splice(1,5);
  var ftA=tA.slice();
  hA.splice(1,5);
  var fA=hA.slice();
  var dstr=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd");
  var html='<style>input{margin:2px 5px 2px 0;}</style><form id="myForm">';
  for(var i=0;i<fA.length;i++) {
    switch(ftA[i]){
      case 'date':
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<br /><input type="%s" value="%s" name="%s" />&nbsp;%s',ftA[i],dstr,fA[i],fA[i]);
        break;
      default:
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<br /><input type="%s" name="%s" />&nbsp;%s',ftA[i],fA[i],fA[i]);
        break;  
    }
  }
  html+='<br /><input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm(this.parentNode)" /></form>';
  return {html:html};
}

function testUpload() {
  upload({'Status':'none', 'Comment':'to long to fit', 'ClientName':'Don Trump', 'RefCode':'Tweeter', 'Final_Status':'impeachment', 'Product':'Bullshit', 'RefId':'id3', 'DaysPassed':'12', 'Final_Status_Date':'2019-12-23', 'Date':'2019-12-23', 'Notes':'none'})
}

function upload(theForm) {
  Logger.log(theForm);
  var kA=Object.keys(theForm);
  kA.splice(kA.indexOf('refId'),1);//remove refID
  Logger.log(kA);
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var hA=sh.getRange(2,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var hObj={};
  hA.forEach(function(e,i){hObj[e]=i+1});
  Logger.log(hObj);
  var vA=sh.getRange(3,1,sh.getLastRow()-2,2).getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(theForm.RefId==vA[i][0]) {
      kA.forEach(function(key){
        Logger.log(hObj[key]);
        Logger.log(theForm[key]);
        sh.getRange(i+3,hObj[key]).setValue(theForm[key]);
      });
    }
  }
  return buildForm();
}

function launchTheFormAsDialog() {
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('theform').setHeight(550);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, "Form Data Entry");  
}
```

theform.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
   $(function(){
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(obj){
        $('#formDiv').html(obj.html);
      })
      .buildForm();
    });
    });
      function submitForm(frmData) {
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(function(obj){
          //console.log('flag1');
          $('#formDiv').html(obj.html);
        })
        .upload(frmData);
      }
      function updateSelect(vA,id){
        var id=id || 'sel1';
        var select = document.getElementById(id);
        select.options.length = 0; 
        for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
          select.options[i] = new Option(vA[i][1],vA[i][0]);
        }
      }
      console.log('My Code');
    </script>
  </head>
   <body>
    <h1 id="main-heading">Form Data Entry</h1>
    <div id="formDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

My Spreadsheet:

I added input data types so that I could initialize the date fields and so that the form could be completely built from data on the Spreadsheet even if columns are added or moved around. You can always hide that row since it's on the top.

[image]

The Dialog:

[image]

Comment: `RefId` should be unique and user has to select it only once. Also, can I show the information i.e company name, contact no. ect. on the left hand side on the same screen.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by refId should be unique.  I was under the impression that the information in blue would be filled in by you.  You can do anything you want with everything to the left of column G. I'm using setValue() to  write to each one of the cells to the right of Column F.

Comment: For example, I'm a user with `AgentId` = `12345` then I should be assigned to only those rows for data entry one by one which rows are pertaining to `id1`. Also, I need your suggestion if we can show the values highlighted in blue on left side of the UI against each unique RefID.

Comment: I have uploaded the sample UI format. Please suggest.

Comment: So the refId is something each user will already know so I’ll change that back to text.

Comment: `RefId` is something which is unique identifier, against which the assigned agent has to do data entry.

Comment: Okay the RefId is no longer drop down selection.  It's a text box that the user is required to know.   Let me know if there is anything else you require.  I know I'm kind of short with the text.  It's just that life has taught be talking get's me in trouble and coding doesn't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204755/discussion-between-vector-jx-and-cooper).

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Google Apps Developer docs have a decent guide for something similar to this:

> Useful for building web apps or adding custom user interfaces in Google Docs, Sheets, and Forms.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html

Looks like you need to grant Google Apps Scripts access, then add one:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone

You can create a standalone script, or manually connect your project:

> Go to Google Drive and click New > More > Connect more apps.
>
> When the "Connect apps to Drive" window appears, type "script" into the search box and press Enter.
>
> Click Connect next to the listing for Google Apps Script.

Google's script example says your scripts would look something like this:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Dialog')
      .addItem('Open', 'openDialog')
      .addToUi();
}

function openDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Dialog title');
}
```

with the corresponding HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
   My Google Sheets Interface.
    <input type="button" value="Close"
        onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
  </body>
</html>
```

There seems to be good documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app

so I'd say that's a good place to start. What you're trying to achieve looks doable for sure, I think it'll be a matter of tweaking it to what google scripts supports.

Good luck!!

Answer (score 2):

If you are familiar with client-side coding frameworks like Angular or ReactJs, the best option is turning the Google sheet into a rest API and use that from client application. [Sheety](https://sheety.co/) is the best free tool to do that.

Otherwise, use the Google Apps script to link a form to a sheet. All are explained [here](https://github.com/jamiewilson/form-to-google-sheets) step by step.

Answer (score 1):

Found this on medium.com https://medium.com/@jaejohns/how-to-use-google-sheets-as-your-website-database-b0f2f13d0396

Could be helpful.