# Make and send email by HTML form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an employee master sheet.
I want to send an email from any row by HTML form (when an menu item is clicked).
I want a Subject field (text box) and message field (paragraph).
After data entry in in these two fields, an email should go to the email of the employee's email ID stored in G column (and some more data stored in other columns)  and the "Subject" (of the email) must be stored in Y column.
I searched in various forums and tried many codes. (like [How to create HTML Data entry form using Google spreadsheet as backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59288795/how-to-create-html-data-entry-form-using-google-spreadsheet-as-backend) ). But, could not succeed. Need help.

Sample sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bQGpy_fEkWFv4tscdDPLI_5jH9i0sOBF8vjfOT151yo/edit#gid=0

Code I tried :

```
//
//
function send_email() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var empsht = ss.getSheetByName("Emp");  
  var currentRow = empsht.getActiveSelection().getRowIndex();
  var empvals = empsht.getRange("A"+currentRow+":B"+currentRow).getValues();
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
    .showModalDialog(html, 'Send an Email to ' + empvals[0][1]);
}
//
//
function send_now() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var empsht = ss.getSheetByName("Emp");  
  var currentRow = empsht.getActiveSelection().getRowIndex();
  var empvals = empsht.getRange("F"+currentRow).getValue();
  MailApp.sendEmail({        to: empvals[0][0],        subject: subject1,        htmlBody: message      });
return data;
}
//
//


//index.html

<br>
Subject       : <input type="text" />
<br>

<br>
Body of email : <input type="text" />
<br>

<br>
<input type="button" value="Send Email" onclick='send_now()'/>

window.getSheetData = function() {

  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
    .send_now();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function send_email() { 
  var html= '<br />Subject: <input type="text" id="sub" /><br />Body of Email: <input type="text" id="bod" /><br /><input type="button" value="Send Email" onclick="sendNow()"/>';
  html+='<div id="msg"></div>';
  html+='<script>function sendNow(){google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(msg){document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML=msg;}).send_now({body:document.getElementById("bod").value,subject:document.getElementById("sub").value});}</script>';
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html), "Email Form");
}

function send_now(obj) {
  var empsh=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var currentRow=empsh.getActiveRange().getRow(); 
  var empval=empsh.getRange(currentRow,6).getValue();
  console.log('Email: %s\nSubject: %s\nMessage: %s',empval,obj.subject,obj.body);
  //MailApp.sendEmail({to:empval,subject:obj.subject,htmlBody: obj.body});
  return "Email Sent";
}
```

Animation:

[image]

This version uses a textarea:

```
function send_email() { 
  var html= '<br />Subject: <input type="text" id="sub" /><br />Body of Email: <textarea rows="4" columns="30" id="bod"></textarea><br /><input type="button" value="Send Email" onclick="sendNow()"/>';
  html+='<div id="msg"></div>';
  html+='<script>function sendNow(){google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(msg){document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML=msg;}).send_now({body:document.getElementById("bod").value,subject:document.getElementById("sub").value});}</script>';
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html), "Email Form");
}
```

Comment: It's almost perfect. I am not able to get "paragraph" for the body of the mail by         var html= '<br />Subject of Email     : <input type="textarea" id="sub" rows="1" cols="50"/textarea>  <br><br/>  <br />Body of Email: <input type="textarea" id="bod" rows="10" cols="60" /textarea>  <br><br/> <br /><input type="button" value="Send Email" onclick="send_now()"/>'  and I want the html dialogue to close once the "Send Email" is clicked.