# Is there a way to grab a result array from a google app script and generate rows the result array has in an html?

Tags: google-apps-script

The script below runs ok, but if I create the html through javascript, I can generate as many rows I need and form_data() will sometimes work. If I generate the html through the html (provided by google app script), I cannot generate as many rows I need and form_data() will work every time.

It is my first time asking here and I do not know if I asked well enough, please let me know if I need to clarify anything! :)
edit: [How to create HTML Data entry form using Google spreadsheet as backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59288795/how-to-create-html-data-entry-form-using-google-spreadsheet-as-backend) this answer is almost the same, however, I need the html to display both the user's input as well as the names matching the numbers given by the user. Think of it as a confirmation screen.

```
function purge() {
/*const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()

  //user enters the following in the prompt:1234,x1,5678,x2,9012,x3
  const res = ui.prompt("Peeps to Purge?",ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL)
  
  const btn = res.getSelectedButton()

  //returns:['1234','x1','5678','x2','9012','x3']
  const mes = res.getResponseText()
  
  if(btn == ui.Button.OK && mes.length >0)
*/
  const mes = ['1234','x1','5678','x2','9012','x3']

  const mesID = mes.filter((e,i) => i % 2 == 0)
  
  const data = dataSS.getRange(3,1,dataSS.getRange("A3:B").getValues().filter(e => e[0] || e[1]).length,2).getValues()
  
  const mesGroups = mes.reduce((r, e, i) => (i % 2 ? r[r.length - 1].push(e) : r.push([e])) && r, [])
  const mesGroupsQuantities = mesGroups.filter(e => data.flat().includes(e[0])).concat(mesGroups.filter(e => !data.flat().includes(e[0])))
  const ifNameNotFound = mesID.map(e => [e,"Please Check ID"]).filter(e => !data.flat().includes(e[0]))

  const sortArray = (mesID, data) => {
    data.sort((a, b) => {
      const aIndex = a[0]
      const bIndex = b[0]
      return mesID.indexOf(aIndex) - mesID.indexOf(bIndex)
    })
  }
  sortArray(mesID, data)
  
  const names = data.filter(e => mesID.includes(e[0])).concat(ifNameNotFound)

  var results = []
  for(var i = 0;i < names.length;i++) {
    results.push([names[i][0],names[i][1],mesGroupsQuantities[i][1]])
  }

  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('StyleSheet').getContent()
  html+= '<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>\n'+
         '<table width="100%">\n'+
         '  <tr>\n'+
         '    <th class="fitwidth">IDs</th>\n'+
         '    <th class="fitwidth">Names</th>\n'+
         '    <th>Quantities</th>\n'+
         '    <th style="width:21px"><div class="note1"><a title="Check the ones you want to confirm">✔</a></div></th>\n'+
         '    <th style="width:21px"><div class="note2"><a title="Check the ones you want to redo">✖</a></div></th>\n'+
         '  </tr>\n'
  for(var i = 0;i < results.length;i++) {
    html+= Utilities.formatString(
         '  <tr align="center">\n'+
         '    <td class="fitwidth">%s</td>\n'+
         '    <td class="fitwidth">%s</td>\n'+
         '    <td>%s</td>\n'+
         '    <td><input type="radio" name="%s" value="confirm" checked></td>\n'+
         '    <td><input type="radio" name="%s" value="redo"></td>\n'+
         '  </tr>\n',
    results[i][0],results[i][1],results[i][2],i,i)
  }
  html+= '</table>\n'+
         '<input type="button" value="Submit" class="action" onclick="form_data()" >\n'+
         '<input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />\n'+
         '<script>\n'+
         '  function form_data(){\n'+
         '    var values = {\n'
  for(var i = 0;i < results.length;i++) {
    html+='"'+i+'":$("input[name='+i+']:checked").val(),'
  }
  html+= '}\n'+
         '  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().filter(values)\n'+
         '  closeIt()\n'+
         '  }\n'+
         '  function closeIt(){\n'+
         '    google.script.host.close()\n'+
         '  }\n'+
         '</script>\n'
  
  var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setWidth(600).setHeight(300)
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface,"Preview Purge List:")
}

function filter(values){
  const submission = Object.entries(values)
  console.log(submission)
}
```

Comment: The question that had been answered is almost the same, however, it does NOT generate as many rows as I need.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue and your goal from your showing script and `I need the html to display both the user's input as well as the names matching the numbers given by the user. Think of it as a confirmation screen.`. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Comment: @Tanaike The character limit here wouldn't let me show my details, but I have written it all in here in the pastebin: https://pastebin.com/0AJ6ZWbf

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, about `Only issue is upon pressing Submit, the form_data() function sometimes works.`, in your showing script, please modify as follows. From `'  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().filter(values)\n'+ '  closeIt()\n'+` to `'  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(closeIt).filter(values)\n'+`. Because `google.script.run` is run with the asynchronous process. Unfortunately, I cannot post this as an answer because your question has already been closed. So, I posted this modification as a comment. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike Hello. Thank you for your answer. I will give you an update when I know for sure the form_data() function is running 100% of the time. 
If possible, could you elaborate on the asynchronous process? It is my first time using a google.script.run in anything :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. About your additional question of ` could you elaborate on the asynchronous process?`, I think that this information might be useful. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing

Comment: Completely works!