# Web App Google Apps Script - Conditional input based on the data selected in a select

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications

In order to obtain the necessary code to get a function that can be executed every time a local is selected in "id-local" and that what it does is the following: with the data that this input has

```
<form class="row g-12 " id="facturacion-form"> 

    <div class="col-md-3 input-group-lg has-validation"> 

     <label for="id-local" class="form-label">LOCAL</label> 

     <select class="form-select" id="id-local" name="id-local" required> 

       <option selected>Elije local</option> <?!=options?> 

     </select> 

  <div class="invalid-feedback"> Por favor elige un local 
  </div> 
</div>
```

look in the google sheets sheet: "XXXXXXXXX", in the sheet with name "DB_LOCALES" in the range "B:O" where in "B" are the name of the premises and in "O" are the name of the companies corresponding, so that in this other input

```
<div class="input-group "> 

   <span class="input-group-text">Sociedad</span> 

   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sociedad-local" placeholder="Cooland Proyect S.L" aria-label="sociedad-local" aria-describedby="sociedad-local"> 

</div>
```

At the moment I have the following function:

```
function updateSociedad() {
  
  var libroLocales = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXXXXXXXXXX");
  var hojaLocales = libroLocales.getSheetByName("DB_LOCALES");
  var rangesoc = hojaLocales.getRange("B:O");
  
  var values = rangesoc.getValues();
  
  var local = document.getElementById("id-local").value;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][0] == local) {
      // Actualizar el valor del campo "sociedad"
      var sociedad = values[i][14]; // Columna "O"
      document.getElementById("sociedad-local").textContent = sociedad;
      break;
    }
   console.log(values);
  }
}
```

but if I put it in the .gs it gives me errors that it can't access the document.getElementById but if I put it in the HTML it shows me that it can't access the spreadsheet

My intention was to create a call to the function from another input, but it is being impossible due to my lack of experience.

I would greatly appreciate help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59513100/7215091 (You can put a select in a form)

Comment: Have you reviewed the [`Class google.script.run (Client-side API)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)? This document will help you a lot in your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- When you select an option of `<select class="form-select" id="id-local" name="id-local" required>`, you want to search a value from the column "B" of `hojaLocales.getRange("B:O")` using the selected value. And, when the value was found, you want to put the value of column "O" of the same row into `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="sociedad-local" placeholder="Cooland Proyect S.L" aria-label="sociedad-local" aria-describedby="sociedad-local">`.

#### Modification points:

- Unfortunately, I cannot know the script for giving `<?!=options?>`. So, in this modification, it supposes that the script for giving `<?!=options?>` are valid values for searching with `hojaLocales.getRange("B:O")`. Please be careful about this.
- In your HTML, in order to send the selected value to Google Apps Script, it is required to communicate between the Javascript side and Google Apps Script side. This has already been mentioned in a comment.
- In your Google Apps Script, there is no `document.getElementById`.
- And, you are retrieving the values from columns "B" to "O" with `var rangesoc = hojaLocales.getRange("B:O");`. In this case, the values are columns "B" to "O". But, in your loop, `var sociedad = values[i][14]; // Columna "O"` is used. In this case, the value is trying to be retrieved from column "P".
- In order to put a value into `input` tag, `value` is used.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following simple modification?

#### HTML & Javascript side:

```html
<form class="row g-12 " id="facturacion-form">
  <div class="col-md-3 input-group-lg has-validation">
    <label for="id-local" class="form-label">LOCAL</label>
    <select class="form-select" id="id-local" name="id-local" required onchange="sample(this);">
       <option selected>Elije local</option> <?!=options?>
     </select>
    <div class="invalid-feedback"> Por favor elige un local
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<div class="input-group ">
  <span class="input-group-text">Sociedad</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sociedad-local" placeholder="Cooland Proyect S.L" aria-label="sociedad-local" aria-describedby="sociedad-local">
</div>

<script>
function sample(e) {
  const value = e[e.selectedIndex].value;
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(sociedad => {
    document.getElementById("sociedad-local").value = sociedad;
  }).updateSociedad(value);
}
</script>
```

#### Google Apps Script side:

In this case, in order to search for value from column "B", TextFinder is used.

```js
function updateSociedad(local) {
  var libroLocales = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXXXXXXXXXX");
  var hojaLocales = libroLocales.getSheetByName("DB_LOCALES");
  var range = hojaLocales.getRange("B1:B" + hojaLocales.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(local).matchEntireCell(true).findNext();
  return range ? range.offset(0, 13).getDisplayValue() : "";
}
```

#### Testing:

When the above HTML is opened as the HTML template, `<?!=options?>` is loaded. And, when you select one of options, the function `sample` is run. And, the selected value is sent to Google Apps Script side with `google.script.run`. And, the value is searched from the column "B". And, when the value was found, the value of column "O" is returned. At Javascript side, the returned value is used in `withSuccessHandler`. And, the value is put into `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="sociedad-local" placeholder="Cooland Proyect S.L" aria-label="sociedad-local" aria-describedby="sociedad-local">`.

#### Note:

Unfortunately, I couldn't know the method for opening the HTML from your question. If you are using Web Apps, please be careful about the following points.

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### Reference:

- [createTextFinder(findText) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createtextfinderfindtext)

Comment: On several occasions you have provided me with solutions that have made me see the light, I am extremely grateful for the work you do for all of us who, like me, are learning. Thank you very much

Comment: @Fabrisimo Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. And, if you got something from this answer, I'm glad. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

> *NOTE: This script is intended to serve as a starting point or reference for your project. It's important to note that the community members do not provide coding services.*

As previously indicated on the comments, implementation of the [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) class is necessary. To facilitate your project, we suggest referring to the following concise example *(added a sample testing button on the html code to run the process)*:

## Script

***Code.gs***

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');//add the of the HTML file for your web app
}

/** SpreadhseetApp doesn't work non-server-side functions (inside JavaScript in HTML), 
 * it has to be processed server side .gs file.
 * */
function updateSociedad(local,sociedad){
  var libroLocales = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXXXXXXX");
  var hojaLocales = libroLocales.getSheetByName("DB_LOCALES");
  var rangesoc = hojaLocales.getRange("B:O");
  var values = rangesoc.getValues().filter(cells => cells.join('').length != 0);

  var results = values.filter(cells => cells[0] == local && cells[13] == sociedad);

  return results;
}
```

***Index.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      /**
       * RUN A SCRIPT AFTER PRESSING THE TEST BUTTON
       */
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
        const input = document.getElementById("sociedad-local");
        const local = document.getElementById("id-local");

        btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
          //USE THIS google.script.run TO RUN SERVICE SIDE APPS SCRIPT FUNCTION CALLED 'updateSociedad()'
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(data => {
            console.log(data);
          }).updateSociedad(local.value,input.value);//Pass Local & sociedad-local values to the server side apps script
        });
      });

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <form class="row g-12 " id="facturacion-form">

      <div class="col-md-3 input-group-lg has-validation">

        <label for="id-local" class="form-label">LOCAL</label>

        <select class="form-select" id="id-local" name="id-local" required>

          <option selected>Elije local</option>
          <?!=options?>

        </select>

        <div class="invalid-feedback"> Por favor elige un local
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="input-group ">

        <span class="input-group-text">Sociedad</span>

        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sociedad-local" placeholder="Cooland Proyect S.L" aria-label="sociedad-local" aria-describedby="sociedad-local">

      </div>

    </form>

    <button id="btn">TESTING</button>

  </body>


</html>
```

## DEMO

- *Sample `DB_LOCALES` sheet data:*

[image]

- *Test running the web app:*

[image]

## References

- [Class google.script.run (Client-side API)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)
- [JavaScript Array filter()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp)
- [Serve HTML as a web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html#serve_html_as_a_web_app)

Comment: Great answer, very elaborate, thank you very much